# Сортировка вектора классов по определенному полю

Tags: c++

Задание такое.
Подготовить программу сортировки информации, находящейся в текстовом файле,
обеспечить возможность сортировки по любому полю (по выбору пользователя), упорядочение при сортировке должно выполняться лексикографически с возможностью изменения его направления (по выбору пользователя), результат сортировки должен выводиться в новый текстовый файл.

Текстовый файл выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс City_loc:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class City_loc {
public:
    // установка названия города
    void set_city_loc_name(string city_loc_name) {
        name = city_loc_name;
    }
    // получение названия города
    string get_city_loc_name() {
        return name;
    }
    // установка названия страны
    void set_city_loc_country(string city_loc_country) {
        country = city_loc_country;
    }
    // получение названия страны
    string get_city_loc_country() {
        return country;
    }
    // установка названия континента
    void set_city_loc_continent(string city_loc_continent) {
        continent = city_loc_continent;
    }
    // получение названия континента
    string get_city_loc_continent() {
        return continent;
    }
    // установка численности населения
    void set_city_loc_people(int city_loc_people) {
        people = city_loc_people;
    }
    // получение численности населения
    int get_city_loc_people() {
        return people;
    }
    // установка проверки столицы
    void set_city_loc_is_capital(string city_loc_is_capital) {
        is_capital = city_loc_is_capital;
    }
    // получение проверки столицы
    string get_city_loc_is_capital() {
        return is_capital;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const City_loc& city_loc) {
        out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.name;
        out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.country;
        out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.continent;
        out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.people;
        out << setw(10) << left << city_loc.is_capital << endl;
        return out;
    }

private:
    string name; // название города
    string country; // название страны
    string continent; // название континента
    int people; // численность населения
    string is_capital; // выделение столицы
};
```

Я вывожу данные в класс City_loc location и объединяю их все в вектор locations. Выглядит это так:

```cpp
City_loc location;
    vector <City_loc> locations;
    string city_loc_name;
    string city_loc_country;
    string city_loc_continent;
    string city_loc_is_capital;
    int city_loc_people;

    string header, line;

    ifstream in_locations; // запись данных из файла
    in_locations.open("City_location.txt");
    if (!in_locations.is_open()) {
        cout << "Sorry, something went wrong";
    }
    else {
        // шапка таблицы
        getline(in_locations, header);
        getline(in_locations, line);
        // запись данных в вектор locations
        while (in_locations >> city_loc_name >> city_loc_country
            >> city_loc_continent >> city_loc_people >> city_loc_is_capital) {

            location.set_city_loc_name(city_loc_name);
            location.set_city_loc_country(city_loc_country);
            location.set_city_loc_continent(city_loc_continent);
            location.set_city_loc_people(city_loc_people);
            location.set_city_loc_is_capital(city_loc_is_capital);

            locations.push_back(location);
        }
    }
    in_locations.close();
```

Затем делаю выбор поля для сортировки и выбор направления сортировки:

```cpp
int field_choice; // выбор поля для сортировки
    cout << "Which field do you want to sort?" << endl;
    cout << "Select a number:" << endl;
    cout << "1. City name" << endl
        << "2. Country" << endl
        << "3. Continent" << endl
        << "4. Population" << endl;
    cin >> field_choice;

    int order_choice; // выбор порядка сортировки
    cout << "Select sort order:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Ascending sort" << endl
        << "2. Descending sort" << endl;
    cin >> order_choice;
```

Затем объединяю данные поля, по которому нужно отсортировать в отдельный вектор:

```cpp
vector <string> city;
    vector <string> country;
    vector <string> continent;
    vector <int> population;

    for (size_t n = 0; n < locations.size(); n++) { // выделение в отдельный вектор поля сортировки
        city.push_back(locations[n].get_city_loc_name());
        country.push_back(locations[n].get_city_loc_country());
        continent.push_back(locations[n].get_city_loc_continent());
        population.push_back(locations[n].get_city_loc_people());
    }
```

Затем присваиваю вектор поля, по которому нужно отсортировать, вектору field:

```cpp
vector <string> field;

    switch (field_choice) {
    case 1:
        field = city;
        break;
    case 2:
        field = country;
        break;
    case 3:
        field = continent;
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Something went wrong, please, try again.";
    }
```

И затем непосредственно сортировка пузырьком:

```cpp
string temp;
    switch (order_choice) {
    case 1: // в порядке возрастания
        for (size_t i = 0; i < field.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < field.size() - i - 1; j++) {
                if (field[j] > field[j + 1]) {
                    temp = field[j];
                    field[j] = field[j + 1];
                    field[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2: // в порядке убывания
        for (size_t i = 0; i < field.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < field.size() - i - 1; j++) {
                if (field[j] < field[j + 1]) {
                    temp = field[j];
                    field[j] = field[j + 1];
                    field[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Something went wrong, please, try again.";
    }
```

Затем создаю новый вектор locations_sort, куда будут помещаться отсортированные элементы:

```
City_loc location_sort;
    vector <City_loc> locations_sort;

    locations_sort.resize(locations.size());
```

**И далее у меня ступор.**
Для сортировки файла по названию города, я помещаю в вектор locations_sort отсортированные значения городов.
Далее сравниваю названия городов из неотсортированного вектора с отсортированным и собираю отсортированный файл (т. е. ставлю страны, континенты и прочие поля на место).

```cpp
switch (field_choice) {
    case 1:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < field.size(); i++) {
            locations_sort[i].set_city_loc_name(field[i]);
        }


        for (size_t i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < locations.size(); j++) {
                if (locations[i].get_city_loc_name() == locations_sort[j].get_city_loc_name()) {

                    locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_country(locations[i].get_city_loc_country());
                    locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_continent(locations[i].get_city_loc_continent());
                    locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_people(locations[i].get_city_loc_people());
                    locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_is_capital(locations[i].get_city_loc_is_capital());
                }
            }
        }
    break;
```

И это работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если собирать таким же способом сортировку по странам, то такой подход не работает, так как есть повторяющиеся значения (в данном случае Russia):

```cpp
case 2:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < field.size(); i++) {
            locations_sort[i].set_city_loc_country(field[i]);
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < locations.size(); j++) {

                    if (locations[i].get_city_loc_country() == locations_sort[j].get_city_loc_country()) {
                            locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_name(locations[i].get_city_loc_name());
                            locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_continent(locations[i].get_city_loc_continent());
                            locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_people(locations[i].get_city_loc_people());
                            locations_sort[j].set_city_loc_is_capital(locations[i].get_city_loc_is_capital());
                    }       
            }
        }
        break;
```

Получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю, какую проверку нужно добавить, чтобы не было таких дубликатов. Пробовала искать повторяющиеся значения, удалять их, но это тоже не работает.
Или для данной задачи нужен совсем другой подход, возможно, более простой. 
Буду очень рада, если поможете с решением :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы слышком все усложняете. Вам нужна всего одна структура для хранения данных:

```
struct City_loc {
    string name{};       // название города
    string country{};    // название страны
    string continent{};  // название континента
    int people{};        // численность населения
    string is_capital{}; // выделение столицы           
};
```

Режим сравнения

```
enum  Mode { cmp1, cmp2, cmp3, cmp4 };
Mode  comparison_mode = cmp1; //по умолчанию
```

оператор сравнения, который сравнивает два экземпляра по установленному режиму сравнения:

```
bool operator <(const City_loc& a, const City_loc& b)
{
    switch (comparison_mode)
    {
    case cmp1:  return a.name < b.name;
    case cmp2:  return a.country < b.country;
    case cmp3:  return a.continent < b.continent;
    default:    return a.people < b.people;     
    }
}
```

можно еще написать операторы ввода и вывода(а можно и не написать, а прямо в программе выполнить то же самое):

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, City_loc& x)
{
    in >> x.name >> x.country >> x.continent
        >> x.people >> x.is_capital;
    return in;
}
 //оператор ввода, который вы написали по своему вкусу
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const City_loc& city_loc) {
    out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.name;
    out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.country;
    out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.continent;
    out << setw(20) << left << city_loc.people;
    out << setw(10) << left << city_loc.is_capital << endl;
    return out;
}
```

и функция(программа) выполняющая чтение, сортировку и запись:

```
//ввод шапки таблицы
//выбор режима сравнения
int choice;
cin >> choice;
switch (choice)
{
case 'a':
    comparison_mode = cmp2; break;
case 'b':
    comparison_mode = cmp3; break;
default: 
    comparison_mode = cmp4; break;
}
/*std::set сразу сохранит в отсортированном виде
    по оператору меньше, поэтому сразу его и исползуем*/
std::set <City_loc> locations;
// ввод из файла
City_loc line;
while (file >> line)
    locations.insert(line);
//запись  в итоговый файл
file2 << header 
      << "\n___________________________\n";
for (const City_loc& x : locations)
    file2 << x;
```

Comment: Ну и, конечно, с увеличением знаний    стандартной библиотеки, модульного программирования,  код напишется  проще.   Но я подумал, что вам  пока  и этот вариант подойдет...